# Simple function to convert decimal number to binary in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a decimal number in binary but I can't seem to understand why my code doesn't work.
Before checking it I need to precise that:

- I am not allowed to use modulo, division, powers, or any libraries
  that might help me to accomplish my goal.
- I can use multiplication, addition, subtraction as well as comparisons.

That said, here is my code:

```py
def binary_conv(n):
    p1 = 1
    p2 = 1
    lst = list()
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0

    while p1 <= n:
        p1 *=2
        counter1 += 1

    len_bin = counter1
    lst = len_bin*[0]
    counter1 -= 1

    while n > 0:
        p2 *= 2
        counter2 += 1
        if (p2*2) == p1:
            lst[counter1-counter2] = 1
            p1 = p2
            p2 = 1
            n = n-p1
            counter2= 0


    print(lst)
```

If you need more clarifications, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: _doesn't work._ What does that mean, specifically?

Comment: I don't get the output wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer, here it is for those interested:

```
def binary_conv(n):
    p1 = 1
    p2 = 1
    lst = list()
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0

    while p1 <= n:
        p1 *= 2
        counter1 += 1

    len_bin = counter1
    lst = len_bin*[0]
    counter1 -= 1

    while n > 0:
        p2 *= 2
        counter2 += 1
        if (p2 * 2) > n:
            if n == 1:
                lst[-1] = 1
                break
            lst[counter1 - counter2] = 1
            p1 = p2
            p2 = 1
            n = n - p1
            counter2 = 0
```